# LaTeX error: "Missing } inserted" when copying the template code

Tags: math-mode, errors

I tried to adapt this part of a template:

```
\begin{align}
y=&ax+b&&\text{(definition of a straight line)}\nonumber\\
  &f'(a)x+b&&\text{(definition of the derivative)}\nonumber\\
  &f'(a)x+f(a)-f'(a)a&&\text{(we know that the line intersects $f$ at $(a,f(a))$}\nonumber
\end{align}
```

By writing:

```
\begin{align}
$c^j_{0}$ = &($x_{j}$-30)^4($x_{j}$-32)^4&&\text{(si $x_{j}$ \in [30,32])}\nonumber\\
            &0&&\text{(sinon)}\nonumber
\end{align}
```

But this error message appears no matter what I try do to to fix it:

```
Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.30 \end{align}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using $ to go into math mode when LaTeX is already in math mode because the `align` environment is usually maths. You still need to go into math mode inside your `\text` bit though, although I expect there's a better way to do it.

Reproducible example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
c^j_{0} = &(x_{j}-30)^4(x_{j}-32)^4&&\text{(si $x_{j} \in [30,32]$)}\nonumber\\
            &0&&\text{(sinon)}\nonumber
\end{align}

\end{document}
```